# How to alert a custom group in slack using incoming webhook

Tags: slack-api, slack

I was trying to alert a custom group using incoming webhook in slack.I can able to alert user using `<@user>`, but with group any of the following format is not working

```
<!cgroup>
<@cgroup>
```

What i am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

From Slack [documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#variables).

> For paid account there is an additional command for User Groups that
>   follows the format `<!subteam^ID|handle>`. (`subteam` is literal text. `ID`
>   and `handle` are replaced with the details of the group.) These indicate
>   a User Group message, and should cause a notification to be displayed
>   by the client. User Group IDs can be determined from the
>   `usergroups.list` API endpoint. For example, if you have a User Group
>   named happy-peeps with ID of `S012345`, then you would use the command
>   `<!subteam^S012345|happy-peeps>` to mention that user group in a
>   message.

It is working great

Comment: I do not see the actual solution in your answer. It just says "... follows the format ." Can you please double check your post. Please also add an example. Finally, mark this as solution to close the question pls.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken please use the usergroups.list api to get the user group id and use that id  in the message .It should be something like this <!subteam^groupid|groupname> "your message"

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it did not display the important parts due to some formatting problems. I fixed it for you.

Comment: I tried this and it worked. It also worked without the handle, so for your example, `<!subteam^S012345>` would produce the same group mention.

Comment: the user group ID can be found easily by navigating to the group in Slack via the browser, not via the desktop/mobile app!

Answer (score 7):

I got this working by adding a `link_names` attribute to my JSON payload. For example, POSTing this to my Slack hook URL:

```
{
    "text": "@myusergroup Hello",
    "link_names": 1
}
```

Caused users in `@myusergroup` to be notified by the message.